# How to say "Completely Custom-Built" in a title in French?

Tags: traduction

Salut!

I want to say "Completely Custom-Built". The context is for applications and software but this is the exact title I want to use and I'm not looking for a title like custom-built apps, etc.

Merci!

Comment: "Custom-built" is *sur mesure*, which you can easily find [in a dictionary](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#en/fr/custom-built). How you say the rest depends on the context. Without more context I would say *entièrement sur mesure* for  "Completely custom-built"

Answer (score 1):

"Completely Custom-Built" can be translated "Entièrement fait sur mesure".